# Linux: look for USB "client" driver example

Tags: usb-drive

I want to write a USB communication driver for Embedded Linux device. The embedded Linux device connects to the Linux PC as a device.
So, I'm going to write two USB drivers, one for Linux PC and one for embedded Linux device.

I can refer to USB-skeleton.c for drivers on Linux PC, but is there a reference code for drivers on embedded Linux device?

Comment: Are you talking about the USB Linux Gadget framework?

Comment: Thanks, I will learn about the Linux Gadget Framework